# Android custom annotation

Tags: android, api, server

I develop an app, which is using a server API for sending and receiving data. The server API has its own version number and I have to check each method, which is using the server API for the server version.
I have declared a custom annotation class:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MinVersion {
   APIVersions version() default APIVersions.FIRST_RELEASE_MARCH_15;
}
```

The method which I have to check is now implemented:

```
@MinVersion(version = APIVersions.APRIL_15)
public void getUser(IUserCallback _callback){
   //Do stuff
}
```

Now I have to call a prepared function to check the server version and if it is too low I want show a dialog, if the method is called.

But at this point I don't know how to implement the handling of the custom annotation.

Is that possible?

Comment: You are using the tag `android-annotations`. This is for the [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) framework. Do you use that, or just want to use an annotation in an Android app?

Comment: No i dont use android-annotations. I want to declare my own annotation